# How to include the `-e` argument in the `$@` bash variable?

Tags: bash, echo

I'm creating a bash script which will wrap a docker run command, passing in all arguments. The docker cmd being run has a `-e` parameter like so:

```
docker run --rm -it --name some_name -v $(pwd):/some_dir some_image some_command -e -r -t
```

However, the bash script for some reason is not passing in the `-e` parameter.

For example I have the following `test.sh` script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Echoing the command arguments."
echo $@
```

The `-e` parameter is not passed through to `$@` when in the first position.

```
$ ./test.sh -e -r -t
Echoing the command arguments.
-r -t

$ ./test.sh -r -e -t
Echoing the command arguments.
-r -e -t
```

Ultimately I would like to be able to call the docker command as follows, simply passing in all given parameters from the bash script to the docker command.

```
docker run --rm -it --name some_name -v $(pwd):/some_dir some_image some_command $@
```

This may be confusing to users if they are expecting the `-e` parameter to be passed in and the associate activity does not happen.

Is there a way to allow the `-e` parameter to pass through?

Comment: That's an `echo` bug. (Literally, a bug; POSIX disallows bash from implementing it the way it does).

Comment: BTW, you should pretty much always use `"$@"` rather than `$@` -- unquoted behavior is identical to `$*`, string-splitting contents and then evaluating each result as a glob before passing them through.

Comment: Supporting a `-e` option makes `echo` non-compliant, not buggy.

Comment: @chepner, ...insofar as bash claims to be POSIX-compliant when `set -o posix` is run or when started under the name `sh`, noncompliance *is* a bug. It's a known bug considered WONTFIX by upstream, granted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your test to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Echoing the command arguments:"
printf ' - %q\n' "$@"
```

...and you'll see `-e` present.

A POSIX-conforming implementation of `echo` will print `-e` on output when given that string as its first argument. bash's implementation does not comply unless both `set -o posix` and `shopt -s xpg_echo` runtime options are set.

Comment: @hooinator Also, note the double-quotes around `"$@"` -- you almost always want those to prevent another bunch of probably-unwanted parsing that the shell does to unquoted variable references.